# Dribble Api returning wrong data

Tags: ios, swift, dribbble-api

Hi guys so recently there has been a bug of getting data from Dribble..

My Dribbble client IOS shows shots on the main screen and if you click on a collectionView Cell it takes you to the detail of the shot..

And i am getting Dribble Data through its api with this method.

The Code for the getShots Method

```
 class func getShots(url: String, callback:(([Shot]) -> Void)){
        var shots = [Shot]()
        let url = url + "&access_token=" + Config.ACCESS_TOKEN

        HttpService.getJSON(url){ (jsonData) -> Void in

            for shotData in jsonData {
                let shot = Shot(data: shotData as! NSDictionary)
                shots.append(shot)
            }

            let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0), { () -> Void in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    callback(shots)
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

The Code for the getJSON method..

```
class HttpService {
    class func getJSON(url: String, callback:((NSArray) -> Void)) {
        let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        Alamofire.request(.GET, nsURL).response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil{
                print("error")
            }

            if data != nil {
                let jsonData = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
                   callback(jsonData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is above which loads The Shot JSON Data successfully..
So when i debug it on the self.shots = shots line it  returns something like this..

[The log when debugging on the self.shots = shots  line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYBXs.png)

It all works fine.. and the code for the class of Detail of a Shot...
I have been using dynamic tableView to show the Shot Detail

The code in ShotDetail the  code where the label are allocated their text.. basically The TableView Data Source Method..

```
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 2
    }




    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if section == 0 {
         return 9
        } else {
         return comments.count
        }
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
         if indexPath.row == 0 {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! vlcTableViewCell

            // Configure the cell
     // the views . likes. and the comment Count label are allocated
            cell.viewsCount.text = "\(shot.viewsCount)"
            cell.likesCount.text = "\(shot.likesCount)"
            cell.commentCount.text = "\(shot.commentCount)"

         return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! descCell

           // Configure the Cell
   // the text for the labels
            cell.usernameLabel.text = "\(shot.user.username)"
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = "\(shot.description)"
            cell.profileImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: shot.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"))

        return cell

        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell4", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! teamCell
            if shot.team == nil{
              cell.teamNameLabel.text = "Team"
            } else {
            cell.teamNameLabel.text = "\(shot.team.name)"
            }
        return cell
        } else  if indexPath.row == 4 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell5", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! reboundShotsCount
            cell.reboundCountLabel.text = "\(shot.reboundCount)"

            return cell

        } else {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell10", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell

            let comment = comments[indexPath.row]
            cell.nameLabel.text = comment.user.name
            cell.commentLabel.text = comment.body

            cell.avatarImageView.alpha = 0.0



            cell.avatarImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: comment.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"), completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) -> Void in
                cell.avatarImageView.alpha = 1.0
                // Animate the imageView after the image is loaded
                cell.animationView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
                cell.animationView.delay = 0
                cell.animationView.duration = 0.5
                cell.animationView.type = "popAlpha"
                cell.animationView.startCanvasAnimation()
            })

        cell.dateLabel.text = comment.date

            return cell
        }
    }
```

and the Code for the Shot Class.. From where i get all the data to set to the labels

```
import Foundation

class Shot: DribbbleBase {

    var imageUrl : String!
    var htmlUrl : String!
    var commentsUrl : String!
    var bucketsUrl : String!
    var likesUrl : String!
    var attachmentUrl : String!
    var reboundUrl : String!

    var title : String!
    var date : String!
    var description : String!
    var commentCount : Int!
    var viewsCount : Int!
    var likesCount : Int!
    var bucketsCount : Int!
    var attachmentsCount : Int!
    var reboundCount : Int!
    var imageUrll : String!
    var teamUrl : String!

    var user : User!
    var team : Team!

   override init(data: NSDictionary) {
        super.init(data: data)

        self.commentCount = data["comments_count"] as! Int
        self.likesCount = data["likes_count"] as! Int
        self.viewsCount = data["views_count"] as! Int
        self.bucketsCount = data["buckets_count"] as! Int
        self.attachmentsCount = data["attachments_count"] as! Int
        self.reboundCount = data["rebounds_count"] as! Int

        self.commentsUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "comments_url")
        self.bucketsUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "buckets_url")
        self.likesUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "likes_url")
        self.title = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "title")
        self.attachmentUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "attachments_url")
        self.reboundUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "rebounds_url")
        self.teamUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "teams_url")

        let dateInfo = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "created_at")
        self.date = Utils.formatDate(dateInfo)

        let desc = Utils.getStringFromJSON(data, key: "description")
        self.description = Utils.stripHTML(desc)

        let images = data["images"] as! NSDictionary
        self.imageUrl = Utils.getStringFromJSON(images, key: "normal")
        self.imageUrll = Utils.getStringFromJSON(images, key: "hidpi")


        let tags = data["tags"] as! NSArray

      if let userData = data["user"] as? NSDictionary {
        self.user = User(data: userData)
    }

    if let teamData = data["team"] as? NSDictionary {
      self.team = Team(data: teamData)
    }

  }
}
```

Now the problem occurs when i tap on the cell to go to the next cell.
before that if i debug in the Shot class..

The data looks like this

[The Log Which shows the data returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7LTL.png)

and now whenever i click on the cell. to go to the detail. the data returns only 7 value for the exact thing which in the first was returning all the values needed..

the code i am using to push the data in PopularShotsCollectionViewController is this.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "1"){
          let selectedItems = collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()

            if let sItem = selectedItems as [NSIndexPath]!{
                let shot = shots[sItem[0].row]
                let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ShotDetail
                controller.shot = shot
            }

        }
    }
```

But the log only returns 7 value in that..

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vkgg7a3f44fg35/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-28%20at%2014.40.23.png?dl=0
```

I have put the link in a code block as i cant post more than 2 links.

Any help will be really appreciated..

Thanks
Aryan

Comment: Your question is extremely vague and includes A LOT of unnecessary code. Could you truncate this a bit and point out the specific problem?

Comment: I have Reduced it @kye if you think it should be more reduced please let me know..

Comment: It could still be reduced a bit (its a lot of code to go through). What exactly is the issue? The detail cell only shows the same values? (If so its probably because you're passing the same data to the `DetailVC` from your `MainVC`, `let shot = shots[sItem[0].row]` might be the issue)

Answer (score 0):

**let shot = shots[sItem[0].row]** Might be the issue. You're passing the same index to the `DetailVC`. You could save an array of the selected shots then pass it to shot variable in your `DetailVC` (If the shot variable is an array of `shots`)

```
var selectedIndex = NSIndexPath()
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        selectedIndex = indexPath
    }
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "1"){
          let selectedItems = collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
              let selectedShots = shots[selectedIndex.row]
                let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ShotDetail
                controller.shot = selectedShots
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This code would not work as you cannot Cannot assign value of type '[Shot]' to type 'Shot!'

Comment: How exactly is the dataSource in your detailVC modeled? Is the an array of `Shots` or just a `Shot` variable? If its just a variable you these no point in getting selected cells. You should move the logic to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and get the `indexPath` of the selected cell then assign it to a variable then `performSegueWithIndentifer`. Answer has been updated